# Selecting random record using LAMBDA expression in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda

I have a SQL table with between 8 and 9 records that hold background configurations for my home page.

I want to randomly select one of them each time the page is refreshed and I want to use a Lambda expression in my controller. Something like:

```
var myRandomSelect = db.MyBackgrounds.Random();
```

That obviously does not work, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a kind of extension method:

```
public static T GetRandom(this IList<T> source)
    {
        var rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        return source.Skip(rnd.Next(0, source.Count())).First();
    }
```

use it like

```
 var myRandomSelect = db.MyBackgrounds.GetRandom();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using EF

```
var random = db.MyBackgrounds
              .OrderBy(c => Guid.NewGuid())
              .FirstOrDefault();
```